# Where should I put functions in Javascript code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I have the following code:

```
(function($) {
  "use strict";

  $(function() {
    // jQuery code here, eg:
    $('body').css('padding-top', $('.nav').height());
    // I want to call that func here...
  });

}(jQuery));
```

And custom function:

```
function xyz(a,b) {
  // do something with "a" and "b"
}
```

Where should I place my custom function? Before `(function($) {`, before `$(function() {`, or inside `$(function() {});`?

Comment: depends on where you are going to use `xyz`

Comment: What do you want to put? Declaration or Defination?

Comment: I want to use it inside $(function() { // I want to call that func here... });

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is the scope.

```
Location              :  Scope
----------------------+--------------------------------------------------------
before (function($) { :  in global scope, easy to call & modify from everywhere 
before $(function() { :  in "source module" scope / jQuery closure
inside $(function() { :  in "$(function" scope
```

So that choice gives you the means to organize the access to your code.
In most cases you want to hide stuff to prevent unintended interactions, but in some cases (e.g. log function), you want to have access from everywhere in your web application.

If you do not need to call `xyz()` from outside `$(function`, keep it inside. If you do just need to call it within the module, keep it inside `( .. (jQuery))`. If you need to call it from everywhere keep it outside in global scope.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to call the function inside the ready handler, declare it inside it

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    "use strict";

    // jQuery code here, eg:
    $('body').css('padding-top', $('.nav').height());
    // I want to call that func here...
    xyz();

    function xyz(a, b) {
        // do something with "a" and "b"
    }
});
```

But if you want to access `xyz` from outside the scope of the dom ready handler you will have to declare it outside the scope of the dom ready handler. Now the method is local to the dom ready handler and thus accessible only inside it.

Also as shown above you can shorten the use of IIFE and dom ready handler as shown above